# How can you save time when writing repetitive code?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, function, loops

I'm trying to create an application in Swift (V2.1.1) and I was wondering if it were possible to shorten this:

```
    Pillar1.center = movePillarUp(Pillar1.center.x, floaty: Pillar1.center.y, pillarNumber: 1)
    Pillar2.center = movePillarUp(Pillar2.center.x, floaty: Pillar2.center.y, pillarNumber: 2)
    Pillar3.center = movePillarUp(Pillar3.center.x, floaty: Pillar3.center.y, pillarNumber: 3)
    Pillar4.center = movePillarUp(Pillar4.center.x, floaty: Pillar4.center.y, pillarNumber: 4)
    Pillar5.center = movePillarUp(Pillar5.center.x, floaty: Pillar5.center.y, pillarNumber: 5)
    Pillar6.center = movePillarUp(Pillar6.center.x, floaty: Pillar6.center.y, pillarNumber: 6)
    Pillar7.center = movePillarUp(Pillar7.center.x, floaty: Pillar7.center.y, pillarNumber: 7)
    Pillar8.center = movePillarUp(Pillar8.center.x, floaty: Pillar8.center.y, pillarNumber: 8)
    Pillar9.center = movePillarUp(Pillar9.center.x, floaty: Pillar9.center.y, pillarNumber: 9)
    Pillar10.center = movePillarUp(Pillar10.center.x, floaty: Pillar10.center.y, pillarNumber: 10)
```

into some sort of function or loop so that I don't have to copy, paste and type in all the numbers manually.

Comment: Use an array, not ten variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you see that your code contains this kind of `xxx1`, `xxx2`, `xxx3` pattern, you know it's better to use an array to store the `xxx`s.

In case you are a beginner of Swift, this is how you would create an array of pillars:

```
let pillarArray = [Pillar1, Pillar2, Pillar3, Pillar4, Pillar5, 
    Pillar6, Pillar7, Pillar8, Pillar9, Pillar10]
```

Then you just loop through the array and call `movePillarUp` on each of the pillars:

```
for (index, pillar) in pillarArray.enumarate() {
    movePillarUp(pillar.center.x, floaty: pillar.center.y, pillarNumber: index + 1)
}
```

That's much cleaner!

Actually, you don't need to create `Pillar1` to `Pillar10` at all! Why not just add it to the array the moment you get the object?

```
var pillarArray = []
pillarArray.append(someMethodThatReturnsAPillar())
```